# Xcode 10 loses support for Subversion. Is there any free alternative?

Tags: xcode, svn, xcode10

[Relese Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes?language=objc)

So in the release note, Apple says that they have removed support for Subversion but I want to know there is any free alternative to use subversion tool freely.

I already heard about [Versions](https://versionsapp.com/), [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/), and [Xversion](https://www.ikoder.com/) etc but this tools are not free.

Comment: Use svnX Its free tool we are using so long and find a tutorial about it https://www.switchingtomac.com/tutorials/get-started-with-subversion-using-svnx/

Comment: please try SVNX (http://www.lachoseinteractive.net/en/community/subversion/svnx/download/)

Comment: @karthikeyan Okay, Thanks.

Comment: @karthikeyan It's not working properly in latest macOS (10.13.6)?

Comment: Our system also same version and xcode10 we dont see any problem

Comment: Okay, I will try and update you.

Comment: The Subvestion itself is F/OSS, and you should have no problems just running its client, `svn`, from a terminal window on your Mac. An added benefit is that it works the same ways on all the supported platforms—Windows, Mac OS, and Linux and \*BSD-based operating systems.